# Postgres - Insert timestamps in an INSERT INTO query while selecting values from tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ecto

I'm trying to run a migration in a Phoenix application, but Postgrex returns the following error:

```
null value in column "inserted_at" violates not-null constraint
```

The query that generated that error is:

```
execute "INSERT INTO contract_groups
  (SELECT c.id, fg.group_id FROM contracts c, folder_groups fg
  WHERE c.folder_id = fg.folder_id)"
```

I tried updating the query to this:

```
execute "INSERT INTO contract_groups
  (contract_id, group_id, inserted_at)
  VALUES ((SELECT c.id, fg.group_id FROM contracts c, folder_groups fg 
  WHERE c.folder_id = fg.folder_id), NOW())"
```

but I get another error saying `subquery must return only one column`.

[This](https://gist.github.com/MarbilleJuntado/3ff2ea054f460607cfab132f38c1167b) is the rough definition of the tables.

Comment: Show us the table definitions.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.  (Unrelated, but still a great tip!)

Comment: Why did you add `VALUES` on second query, usually used without `SELECT`?

Comment: @jarlh Please see the gist in the updated description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into contract_groups (contract_id, group_id, inserted_at)
select c.id, fg.group_id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
from contracts c
inner join folder_groups fg
on fg.folder_id = c.folder_id
```

Note, this relies on the columns selected matching the order of the columns in statement

UPDATE:

As per comment, try:

```
insert into contract_groups (contract_id, group_id, inserted_at)
select distinct c.id, -- distinct added to prevent duplicates
                fg.group_id, 
                CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
from contracts c
inner join folder_groups fg
on fg.folder_id = c.folder_id
where not exists ( -- exclude any combos that are in the target table
                 select 1 
                 from contract_groups cg
                 where cg.contract_id = c.id
                 and fg.froup_id = cg.group_id
                 )
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to add `updated_at` with value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as well since it has a non-null constraint like `inserted_at`.

One more question though, how do I make sure this will only insert unique pairs of `contract_id` and `group_id` values that are still non-existent in the `contract_groups` table?